# can't get result from sp into array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the result of a stored procedure in `MySQL` into an array with use of `php`. The code I have:

```
function get_all_uzovi($dbc) {

    //$query = "SELECT diagnose_id, diagnose_code, specialisme_agb_code_fk 
    //       FROM tbl_diagnoses
    //       WHERE specialisme_agb_code_fk = '$var_chosen_specialism' 
    //       ORDER BY diagnose_code ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"CALL spGetUzovi");

    //WHAT DOES NOT WORK:
    //$data = array();
    //while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    //  $data[] = $row;
    //}
    //return json_encode($data);

    //WHAT DOES WORK:
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
          echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1];

      }


}
```

The code under "//WHAT DOES NOT WORK" is what I need: the result as a `json` format. For some reason it gives me nothing..

The code under "//WHAT DOES WORK", does work, but this is not what I want.

the code for the sp:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ziekenh3`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spGetUzovi`()
    NO SQL
SELECT *
FROM tbl_uzovi
```

the code that I use when working with queries (which does work) instead of sp:

```
function get_diagnoses($dbc,$var_chosen_specialism) {

    $query = "SELECT diagnose_id, diagnose_code, specialisme_agb_code_fk 
             FROM tbl_diagnoses
             WHERE specialisme_agb_code_fk = '$var_chosen_specialism' 
             ORDER BY diagnose_code ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    $data = array();
    //while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    return json_encode($data);  
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be useful to see the stored proceedure.

Comment: Why do you mix procedural and object calls of mysqli? Stick to one way and it will work.

Comment: I have the feeling that its in the stored procedure. When I use the code that does not work with a query that I write in php, then it does work. I made the sp in `phpMyAdmin`. the sp has nog IN or OUT parameters, and the SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM tbl_uzovi`.

Comment: Well add it to your question

Comment: If the second loop works, so should the first. They're both processing the same `$row` data.

Comment: I changes the `new_procedure` for `spGetUzovi`, but still doen't work

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```html
function get_all_uzovi($dbc) {

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"CALL spGetUzovi");

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: No, undefined offset for 0 and 1. And I dont get the column names of the result of the sp.

Comment: What kind of JSON response are you expecting?

Comment: I've posted the code that I use when working with a query instead of a sp in my querstion. This does work, but when I replace the query for the sp, then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Have made an edit. Was fetching an associative array and still specifying indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it. A bit of a stupid problem: there where some fields in the result set that contained characters like: , ( . etc. I don't think `json` likes this..

When I did a  `SELECT * FROM` on another table it worked. So, my code that works now is:

```
function get_all_uzovi($dbc) {

    $q = "CALL spGetUzovi";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    return json_encode($data);

}
```

I'm sorry for the inconvenience!